# LED light transmission through prepreg in a PCB

Tags: led, light

I've designed a LED board 8x8 where LEDs are assembled in reverse. So, there is a through hole at every LED position, LEDs assembled at the bottom, and light goes through the PCB hole and comes out the top layer.

The issue is that I notice some portion of light going through the PCB prepreg to the adjacent LED which is lit up a bit.

The first batches were OK because the prepeg had a darker color and now with a new supplier it is more transparent. What I would need is to spec the type of prepreg and core dielectrics correctly.

Which type of prepreg do I have to use to avoid LED light transmission through the PCB substrate?

---

This is a comparison for your consideration:

[image]

Comment: Can you convert those light-transmitting through holes to plated-through holes? The plating should block the light.

Comment: How about using a row of vias as a light blocker between each pair of LEDs?

Comment: Both ideas seems very interesting and good but the topic is that i've got in prodcution the PCBs.
the first batchs were OK because the prepeg had a darker color and now with a new supplier it is more transparent.
What i would need is to specy correctly the typr of prepeg and core dielectrics and I don't know much about it

Comment: From my point of view is how to specify prepreg an core to avoid such an issue

Comment: Pre-preg is not very thick. How do you know that is the issue?

Comment: It would have been helpful, and considerate to the readers, if you had mentioned in the original question that you could not modify the PCB. Any other details we need to know?

Comment: Have you asked the same question from the PCB manufacturer?

Comment: I haven't talked with the manufacturer still

Comment: No more details.

Comment: Pcb from manufacturer 1:ok Pcb from manufacturer 2: light go through substrate and affectation in other position

Comment: show photo of clear details

Comment: Use copper inner layer to block off unwanted light transmission?

Comment: "prepreg", so this is more than 2 layers?

Comment: use plated holes and black* solder mask.  (or some colour that looks black under the LED illumination)

Comment: is FR2 an option? that stuff is opaque, but you might be stuck with single layer.

Comment: no FR2, needed FR4

Comment: I SEND A COMPARATIVE IN JPG

Comment: @MaxJosel - Hi, You put new info (example images) in an "answer" - that's not allowed on Stack Exchange as it isn't an *answer*. But then you deleted that non-answer, so the images are only viewable by site members with >10k points. That's not a good solution. I will move your new info into the question as an update, where it belongs. Please note that Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more info. Thanks.

Comment: which LED (model number) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your deleted photos are unclear about the LEDs but this transparency would have been corrected by specifying a black solder mask on both sides.
[image]

1. optical crosstalk demands careful design specs. to avoid unintended effects.
2. FR4 is made from epoxy resin with fibreglass and sheets are normally opaque, soldermask can vary widely.
3. tinted FR4 requires a special request from supplier and not common stock so soldermask is used for tinting
4. Bending leads of thru-hole LEDs must be done per the datasheet to avoid common faults as sheered gold-wire bonds are common otherwise.
5. The clear epoxy in LEDs is softer at solder temps. and lead stress/ bends must never be made < 5mm from the base and manual solder time = 3 s, and more can induce thermal stress from thermal gradients.
6. Handling with ESD safe practice and if open bagged, may need oven drying depending on solder method.
7. absorbed moisture can have thermal popcorn effect micro stress on micron thin gold wire bond as clear epoxy is more prone to moisture ingress compared to black epoxy.

I have found the best way to eliminate optical crosstalk and reduce beamwidth is to use a black heat shrink. I choose the desired length over the lens body. This can also reduce beam spread if desired.

BIVAR also has many solutions.

Comment: OP didn’t ask about 4-7.

Comment: epoxy is usually traslucent, not opaque.

Comment: FR4 has fiberglass that makes the epoxy opaque

Comment: I think Tony that epoxy is traslucent, that coul d could be the key of the issue

Comment: It`s hard to say without examining all the dimensions of the lens and FR4 and variations in LEDs, insertion depth, and tangential leakage of reflector cup with focal angle.  Who can guess without all this detail/<

Comment: below a comparison

Comment: it might have nothing to do with pre-preg

Comment: Do you know how to specify prepeg and fr4 to get the left side pcb of the comparison?

Comment: Max your photos are unclear about everything.  Transparent substrate of LEDs, different LED's translucency on PCB is not much different. What is the real issue? None of this is clear. If you want dark PCB's you specify that in the solder mask. But why is there one LED on the left like all the ones on the right?